# Design time data for both ViewModel and DependencyProperties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I've been using the `d:DataContext` property to provide design-time representations of my view models to my views, but I've now encountered a situation where my view has also has XAML bindings to a number of a number `DependencyProperty`members I've declared in the view control that I'd also like to populate with design time data.

How can I provide design time data for both my ViewModel (via sample data) and the control's dependency properties?

Obviously I can just roll all of the properties into my ViewModel to avoid the problem, but I'd rather not, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workable solution for my case was to use `d:DataContext` to provide design-time data representing my view model and use the `Binding FallbackValue` property to provide the design-time data for my View UserControl's dependency properties.

If no `DataContext` is provided, these fallback values will leak into run-time, but for a MVVM view this shouldn't really be an issue.

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         x:Name="myView" 
         x:Class="Example.MyView" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"                        
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/MyViewModelSampleData.xaml}">

        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myView, Path=ADependencyPropertyOnMyView}"/>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to tell you how to do anything specific with the source of those dependency properties without knowing what the source of the dependency properties is.  ViewModel is easy: just load it with data at design time.  Technically, the answer is to simply populate those properties with values at design time.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  The dependency properties are properties I've implemented in the control.  Essentially, they are properties that provide label content and I'd rather not specify the labels in the ViewModel (although I certainly could).

Comment: If they're binding to other properties on the control, you can simply populate those values at design time, either in the construction of the form or in the construction of the control.  To detect whether you're in design mode at run-time, you can use `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(
    new DependencyObject());`

Comment: Actually, populating the DependencyProperty values in the constructor was the first thing I tried, however they don't appear in the designer.  I just discovered a work-around, however-- using a FallbackValue in the Binding XAML.  Not ideal since it could leak into runtime, but that shouldn't be an issue in my use case.

Comment: Did you do it after the call to `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: Yep, I tried both before and after. Go figure.  I expected it to work, too.  I feel like I've done this in the past...

Comment: I just realize that populating values in the constructor works at design time if I'm hosting my UserControl in another control, however I'm trying get default values in the designer for the UserControl itself.